# Vue Conditional rendering giving error against conditional

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to learn Vue and am having trouble with conditional rendering. It is not breaking the app but it's giving me a console error.

Initially, character is an empty object.

I am trying to only render the card when a character exists (when a button is pressed). Currently I am getting the error

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
```

Currently a card does not render until it is supposed to, but it is giving me those errors.

My Component is:

```
<template>
  <v-card v-if="character" min-width="350" outlined>
    <div class="d-flex flex-no-wrap justify-space-between">
      <v-avatar class="ma-3" size="125" tile>
        <v-img :src="character.image"></v-img>
      </v-avatar>

      <div>
        <v-card-title class="secondary--text text-h6">{{
          character.name
        }}</v-card-title>
        <v-card-subtitle class="secondary--text"
          >Featured in {{ character.episode.length }} episodes</v-card-subtitle
        >
        <v-card-subtitle class="secondary--text pb-0 pt-0">{{
          character.species
        }}</v-card-subtitle>
        <br />

        <v-card-subtitle class="secondary--text pt-0"
          >Origin: {{ character.origin.name }}</v-card-subtitle
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-card>
  <div v-else></div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
export default {
  name: 'CharacterCard',
  computed: mapGetters(['character'])
};
</script>
```

Comment: It seems `character.episode` is undefined here. I would add `v-if="character.episode"` to `v-card-subtitle` to cover this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said

> Initially, character is an empty object.

and then you are trying to access `character.episode.length` which is giving the error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"` because `character.episode` is undefined, which has no property 'length'

There are several potential solutions. Here are a few:

- `(character.episode || []).length`
- `character.episode && character.episode.length || 0`
- `character.episode?.length || 0` note - may require some babel magic to get optional chaining to work. see: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/does-vue-cli-3-come-with-pre-configured-optional-chaining/42609

You could either put this directly in the template in-line, or it would may be better to put it in a computed property.